# VSCode: How to remove "Test framework ... is not installed. Install?" from a multi-folder workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have an open workspace in vscode, in which I have three separate projects: only one of the three projects contains python code, the other two do not.

Every time I open the tests sidebar that allows me to run the python tests, I get a popup message that says

```
Test framework pytest is not installed. Install?
```

I would like to remove this popup as it's quite annoying. Any idea on how to do it? I tried to click "No" but the popup keeps displaying after every vscode restart. Also, in the tests section, all three project folders are displayed, so this makes me think that vscode assumes that tests for those folders are enabled.

For reference, the test sidebar I'm talking about has this icon

[image]

and the message is this

[image]

Comment: Where did you specify you test setttings for the Python extension? Just in the one workspace or at the multi-root workspace level?

Comment: I have a .vscode folder in the main project only, the other two don't have any config

Comment: Is pytest installed in the environment you have configured for the workspace with Python code?

Comment: @BrettCannon yes

Comment: Then please open a but at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.